# Extracting Hour from a factor for an entire column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with time that is in factor class and a hour which is blank.

I want to strip the hour off of each time column and put it in the hour column

```
 time<- factor(c("13:30:00.994","19:15:20.300"))
 time
 hour<-c(0,0)
 hour
 data<- as.data.frame(cbind(hour, as.character(time)))
 data
 data$hour<-strsplit(as.character(time),":")[[1]][1]
 data

  data
   hour           V2
 1   13 13:30:00.994
 2   13 19:15:20.300
```

but LOOK AT THE HOUR COLUMN 13 13 vs 13 19

the out put should strip the 19 so it should look like this:

```
 data
   hour           V2
 1   13 13:30:00.994
 2   19 19:15:20.300
```

Comment: look at the HOUR columns 13 13 vs 13 19

Comment: The reason they are both `13` is your `strsplit` returns a list, and you reference explicitly the first substring of the first member of the list. The `19` is in `list[[2]][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `hour` always the first two characters of your data frame? If so it might be easier to use `substr()`:

```
df <- data.frame(time = as.factor(c("13:30:00.994","19:15:20.300")))
transform(df, hour = substr(time, 1, 2))
#           time hour
# 1 13:30:00.994   13
# 2 19:15:20.300   19
```

Comment: I was just about post this exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> data$hour = sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$V2),':'), function(x) x[1])
> data
  hour           V2
1   13 13:30:00.994
2   19 19:15:20.300
```